# Sending lambda to CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION crashes?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have the following code:

```
std::string stream;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, & stream);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, [](void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count, std::string *stream) -> size_t {
  auto s_size = size * count;
  stream->append((char *)buffer, 0, s_size);
  return s_size;
});
```

It compiles and it crashes. If I replace the lambda by a function, it works fine:

```
static size_t _writefunction(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count, std::string *stream) {
  auto s_size = size * count;
  stream->append((char *)buffer, 0, s_size);
  return s_size;
}
```

Is there any way to use a lambda instead of a separated function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`curl_easy_setopt` [is documented](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) with the signature

```
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLoption option, parameter);
```

where the `parameter` is allowed to be one of several types depending on the `option`. Clearly, (as a C API, where C has no overloading) it must be doing something strange, and this is borne out by looking at [the source](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/19a82c12c098ec201fe3a03c6b5dcc8962843864/include/curl/easy.h#L42), where we see `curl_easy_setopt` is implemented with varargs.

```
CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, ...);
```

So the problem with passing a lambda to `curl_easy_setopt` is that it is getting passed in *as is*, since `curl_easy_setopt` says it can take objects of any type. The actual object represented by a lambda expression is just a `struct` of the captures; in this case, you're just passing an empty `struct` object to `curl_easy_setopt` when it is expecting a function pointer. Chaos ensues.

Lambdas with no captures may be explicitly converted to function pointers by using unary `+`.

```
//                                            v one char fix!
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, +[](void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count, std::string *stream) -> size_t {
  auto s_size = size * count;
  stream->append((char *)buffer, 0, s_size);
  return s_size;
});
```

This conversion can also happen implicitly, but `curl_easy_setopt` doesn't provide any type information and thus doesn't trigger the conversion automatically.

Comment: The plus sign worked like magic! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`curl_easy_setopt` is actually a C function defined as:
`curl_easy_setopt(struct Curl_easy *data, CURLoption tag, ...)` ([source](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/19a82c12c098ec201fe3a03c6b5dcc8962843864/lib/setopt.c#L3191)). C does not know lambdas, but knows function pointers.

The ellipsis (`...`) is a C way of doing variadic functions. A more familiar example of variadic function is `printf`. In general this is very delicate matter, as the compiler does not know about types of parameters expected to be passed through the operator. In particular, it does not know that the lambda should actually be a function pointer. Otherwise it would either convert it correctly or raise a compile error.

If you used printf, you probably faced a situation when it was printing garbage, or outright crashed, because incorrect arguments were passed.